# What is the difference between factory method and utility classes?

Tags: java

What is the difference between factory method and utility classes? When we use factory method and when we use utility classes?

Comment: [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), [utility pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_pattern).

Comment: They have nothing in common other than their use of static methods.

Comment: Factories make things.  Utility classes do things (other than making things).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942882/what-are-and-the-difference-between-factories-service-and-util-classes-are-t

Answer (score 5):

From Wikipedia

> In object-oriented programming, a factory is an object for creating
>   other objects – formally a factory is simply an object that returns an
>   object from some method call, which is assumed to be "new".
>   [Factory method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)
>
> In computer programming, a utility class is a class that defines a set
>   of methods that perform common, often re-used functions. Most utility
>   classes define these common methods under static (see Static variable)
>   scope.
>   [Utility Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_pattern)

I think you can guess the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Basicaly, factory is used to create object (view for example), you can create different object with one factory by different requests that u can perform

Utility class it's a class with static methods that you call to perform some operation (for example some complex operation with number or strings manipulation) but without dependence with other class.

I read that use Utility class it's bad programming but I'm not agree with this

Comment: Looking up the difference between Scala's "class" and "object" definitions might help with understanding (Scala is very similar to Java).

Answer (score 0):

**Factory design pattern:-**
In Factory pattern, we create object without exposing the creation logic to the client and refer to newly created object using a common interface.
**Utility classes:-**
utility class consists exclusively of static methods that operate on or return collections